Derivative bounded below and preimage of compact set is compact
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, and assume that $\vert f'(x) \vert \ge 1$,  for all $x \in  \mathbb{R}$. Then for each compact set $C \subset \mathbb{R}$, the set $f^{-1}(C)$ is compact.
And it is given that statement is true.
I understand the case when $\vert f(x)\vert\ge M \lVert x \rVert$ this is true by showing boundedness for $f^{-1}(C)$. Was trying to use similar argument here but not sure how to related bound of derivative to function. Please help.

With Lagrange's theorem, I guess.

$f^{-1}(C)$ is closed because $C$ is closed and $f$ is continuous. It remains to show that $f^{-1}(C)$ is bounded, and that follows immediately from the mean-value theorem:
For all $x \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
\begin{align}
 |f(x) - f(0)| &= \underbrace{|f'(c)|}_{\ge 1} \cdot |x-0|  \quad \text{(for some $c \in \Bbb R$)}\\
&\ge |x| 
\end{align}
$$
so that
$$
 |x| \le |f(x) - f(0)| \le |f(x)| + |f(0)| \, .
$$
$C$ is compact and therefore bounded, say $|y| \le M$ for all $y \in C$.
Then $|x| \le M + |f(0)|$ for all $x \in f^{-1}(C)$, so that $f^{-1}(C)$ is bounded as well.

May be very trivial thing but confusing does mean value theorem holds here? In that case what is the closed interval ?

@dhashtp: Yes, the mean-value theorem holds.  The interval is the interval from $0$ to $x$, so either $[0, x]$ or $[x, 0]$, depending on the sign of $x$.

Yes got it now. I guessed this should be the closed interval just confirmed. Thank you

As derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property (by Darboux's Theorem), from the fact that $|f'(x)|\geq 1$ we deduce either $f'(x)\geq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $f'(x)\leq -1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. WLOG, let's assume the former.
As $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is continuous too. Given any compact set $C$, we have that $C$ is closed and so by continuity $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed as well.
Given that $f'(x)\geq 1$, we have $f(x)\geq f(0)+x$ for $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)\leq f(0)+x$ for $x\leq 0$. This implies that $f$ is surjective.
As $C$ is compact, we know both $a=\inf(C)$ and $b=\sup(C)$ exist. Because $f$ is surjective and strictly monotonic, we can find $c=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)\geq a \}$ and $d=\sup\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)\leq b \}$.
We will then have $f^{-1}(C)\subseteq [c,d]$ and thus $f^{-1}(C)$ is bounded too, which implies it is compact.
